# Junit test coverage ReadWriteLock

Tags: junit, mocking, code-coverage, mockito, eclemma

I am trying to reach high % coverage using EclEmma on a piece of code and I am having problem covering the following:

```java
public class foo() {

    ReadWriteLock compositeLock;

    @VisibleForTesting
    @Guardedby("compositeLock")
    public class String far() {
        compositeLock.getLock().unlock();
        try {
            //code..
            return answer;
        } finally { 
            compositeLock.getLock().lock();
        }
    }
}
```

I am missing coverage on the `finally` part, should I use mockito and mock the ReadWriteLock? Or is mocking not needed?

Comment: Have you written unit test for ReadWriteLock? BTW, the purpose of unit testing is not just to improve the coverage!

Comment: I just reformatted your code, but reading it: You **un**-lock before doing things and then lock within finally?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your coverage tool.  If you're testing this method at all, then the `finally` clause is being run.  It seems odd to me that a coverage tool would claim that you haven't covered it.